# Responsive email with Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, responsive

do you know if it is possible to send responsive email through Outlook? For example to collapse some section if button are pressed?
I don't find much on Internet on that.
Thanks for the help

I have tried to do some research but I don't find anything on internet.

Answer (score 0):

Email clients such as Outlook don't support running any JavaScript (or any other scripts) embedded into the message body.

But you may find [Actionable messages in Outlook and Office 365 Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/) helpful. Office 365 provides two solutions to enhance productivity with Outlook Actionable Messages: actionable messages via email, and actionable messages via Office connectors.

See [Outlook version requirements for actionable messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/#outlook-version-requirements-for-actionable-messages) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

Outlook renders email according to the MS Word engine, so it's basically a static print page. In inches instead of pixels!

If you were to resize the screen, it wouldn't change width. (Though in the same email you can send it in a way that it will be responsive/interactive for other email clients.)

No Javascript, no advanced CSS, no hide/not hide.

They added support for animated GIFs a couple of years back- that's about all that moves!